# SQLalchemy append dataframe to existing SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to append two columns from a dataframe to an existing SQL server table. The code runs but when I query the SQL table, the additional rows are not present. What am I missing?

```
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://user:pw@host:port/dbname?driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server")

df.to_sql(name='database.tablename', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use dot notation in the `name=` parameter. Just use `name=tablename`. The other parts are fine.

If you need to assign a non-default (`dbo`) schema, there is a `schema=` parameter for `df.to_sql()`. The prefix `database.` is redundant because you have already assigned `dbname` in the engine.

Tested with SQL Server 2017 (latest docker image on debian 10) and anaconda python 3.7.

Test code

SQL Server part (create an empty table)

```
use testdb;
go

if OBJECT_ID('testdb..test') is not null
    drop table test;
create table test (
    [Brand] varchar(max),
    [Price] money
);
```

Python part

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import sqlalchemy

# check your driver string
# import pyodbc
# pyodbc.drivers()  # ['ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server']

# connect
eng = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://myid:mypw@localhost:1433/testdb?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server")

df = DataFrame(
    data={'Brand': ['A','B','C'],
          'Price': [10.00, 20.00, 30.00]}, 
    columns=['Brand', 'Price']
)
df.to_sql(name="test", schema="dbo", con=eng, if_exists="append", index=False)
```

Result

```
select * from [test]

| Brand | Price   |
|-------|---------|
| A     | 10.0000 |
| B     | 20.0000 |
| C     | 30.0000 |
```