# Python dataframe to SQL Server writing problem

Tags: python, sql-server, dataframe

I can connect to the sql-server database and read data from python using,

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server_name;DATABASE=testdb;UID=Another_Domain\\username;PWD=pass; Trusted connection=YES')
```

But when I try to write data from python to sql-server using,

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://user:password@host:port/myDB')
conn = engine.connect()
```

I get an error,

```
InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)
```

How can I connect?

Comment: Unrelated, specifically, to the question you're asking, however, if you're using a Trusted connection in the first statement, why are you passing a Username and password? It's one or the other.

Comment: The second block seems to come from `sqlalchemy`, and its connection syntax is very different from pyodbc. You have to assign the driver string explicitly. You may refer to the following MWE (minimum working example) and see if it works. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60636359/3218693

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the way you can connect is:

```
create_engine('mssql+pymssql://{domain}\{username}:{password}@{hostip}:{port}/{db}')
```